# Python, concise way to test membership in collection using partial match

Tags: membership, collections, python

What is the pythonic way to test if there is a tuple starting with another tuple in collection?  actually, I am really after the index of match, but I can probably figure out from test example

for example:

```
c = ((0,1),(2,3))
# (0,) should match first element, (3,)should match no element
```

I should add my python is 2.4 and/or 2.5

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
Thanks to the OP for the addition explanation of the problem.
[S.Mark's nested list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696432/python-concise-way-to-test-membership-in-collection-using-partial-match/2696522#2696522) are pretty wicked; check 'em out.

I might opt to use an auxiliary function:

```
def tup_cmp(mytup, mytups):
    return any(x for x in mytups if mytup == x[:len(mytup)])

>>> c = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5))
>>> tup_cmp((0,2),c)
False
>>> tup_cmp((0,1),c)
True
>>> tup_cmp((0,1,2,3),c)
True
>>> tup_cmp((0,1,2),c)
True
>>> tup_cmp((2,3,),c)
True
>>> tup_cmp((2,4,),c)
False
```

---

Original answer:
Does using a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) work for you?:

```
c = ((0,1),(2,3))

[i for i in c if i[0] == 0]
# result: [(0, 1)]

[i for i in c if i[0] == 3]
# result: []
```

List comps were [introduced in 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Comment: yes, it works for me. However I really like to know how to compare tuples, rather than individual members, e.g. `(0,1,2) == (0,1,2,3)[:len(((0,1,2)))]` (which does not seem pythonic)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> c = ((0,1),(2,3))
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((0,),x))]
[(0, 1)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((0,1),x))]
[(0, 1)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((2,),x))]
[(2, 3)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((2,3),x))]
[(2, 3)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((4,),x))]
[]
```

With larger Tuple

```
>>> c=((0,1,2,3),(2,3,4,5))
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((0,1),x))]
[(0, 1, 2, 3)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((0,2),x))]
[]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((2,),x))]
[(2, 3, 4, 5)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((2,3,4),x))]
[(2, 3, 4, 5)]
>>> [x for x in c if all(1 if len(set(y)) is 1 else 0 for y in zip((4,),x))]
[]
>>>
```

**Edit**: more compact one would be

```
>>> [x for x in c if all(len(set(y))==1 for y in zip((0,),x))]
[(0, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: okay, slight modification `[x for x in c if all(len(set(y)) is 1 for y in zip((0,),x))] `

Comment: Oh, I just posted similar one too @aaa with ==1, may be 2 space less

Answer (score 1):

my own solution, combination of two other answers

```
f = lambda c, t: [x for x in c if t == x[:len(t)]]
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question :-) And thanks for expanding on your problem.  I posted something similar in my answer.